# How to test for the second parameter of a mocked method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I am trying to mock the `sendEmails()` method and would like to test if the second parameter is called with "test@test.com" email address.

```
@mock.patch('apps.dbank.management.commands.optin_invites.OptinBase.sendEmails')
def test_x_send_emails(self, send_emails_mock):
   oi = OptinInvitesX()
   oi.compute(True, "test@test.com")
   self.assertTrue(send_emails_mock.assert_called_with(???, test_email_address="test@test.com"))
```

I could utilise `assert_called_with` but I don't care about the first parameter for this test case.  Is there a way to say accept anything for first parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of [`mock.ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.ANY):

> Sometimes you may need to make assertions about *some* of the arguments in a call to mock, but either not care about some of the arguments or want to pull them individually out of `call_args` and make more complex assertions on them.
>
> To ignore certain arguments you can pass in objects that compare equal to everything. Calls to `assert_called_with()` and `assert_called_once_with()` will then succeed no matter what was passed in.

So, in your case, you could use:

```
# only asserting on 'test_email_address' argument:
send_emails_mock.assert_called_with(mock.ANY, test_email_address="test@test.com")
```

Note that you don't really want to use `self.assertTrue` on that line. The mock method is its own assertion.